# How to write more than 100 differential equation in MATLAB ode function and to solve it?

Tags: function, matlab, for-loop, ode

I want to solve 100 differential equation by ode45. My entire 100 ode equation has same pattern i.e. in the form of xdot= A*x + B*y + C*u where xdot, A, B and C have n*1 order. So the first equation is xdot(1)=A(1)*x(1) + B(1)*y(1) +C(1)*u(1) and nth equation is xdot(n)= A(n)*x(n) + B(n)*y(n) +C(n)*u(n). It is very hectic to write this 100 equation in function script file of ode MATLAB. My question is that how to write this hundred equation using **for** loop or any other methods in MATLAB function script and solve the ode equation ?

Answer (score 2):

You can define your system using matrices instead of a list of ODE's.

Given your vectors `a`, `b` and `c`

```
A = diag(a); B = diag(b); C = diag(c);
xdot = @(x, y, u) A*x + B*y + C*u;
```

then solve `xdot` using some solver like `ode45`.

### Edit

Of course you can also use dot-notation. I initially wrote my answer in matrix form due to that being the standard in linear algebra.

```
xdot = @(x, y, u) a.*x + b.*y + c.*u;
```

Comment: Is xdot written in function script?

Comment: You can write it as an [anonymous function](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/anonymous-functions.html) @aman2909.

Comment: I got an error. Another question is how to define x,y and u.                                                                                                              Matrix dimensions must agree.

Error in Matrix>@(x,u)A.*x+B.*u (line 45)
xdot = @(x,u) A.*x + B.*u;

Error in odearguments (line 90)
f0 = feval(ode,t0,y0,args{:});   % ODE15I sets args{1} to yp0.

Error in ode45 (line 115)
  odearguments(FcnHandlesUsed, solver_name, ode, tspan, y0, options, varargin);

Error in Matrix (line 48)
[ts,solution]=ode45(xdot, tspan,x0);